How to Sing while playing a complex or off-beat lead guitar or bass line (no chord struming)
So far, I am able to strum guitar chords and do regular fingerpicking/arpeggios while singing. However, I still struggle to sing while playing complex guitar leads (compared to the vocal melody).
Things that I have tried in order to fix this include:

Training with simple songs like Come As You Are (Nirvana) and You Really Got Me (The Kinks).

Moving my body as little as possible, not even tapping my feet on the ground as it locks your voice more.

Omitting some words from the lyrics when I sing, and only adding the missing words when I feel fully comfortable.


Is the progress I am making going to be permanent?
Can this skill be generalized to many kinds of songs, or will I have to put in this work again for every riff I want to learn?
Can this skill be applied to other kinds of stringed instruments?

This question is similar to: Learning to sing while playing a syncopated strum. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Struming is off topic for this question as it is much easier to do the Struming/singing combo compared to off-beat riffing hile singing.

@v-g The basic concept is identical: learning to coordinate hands/fingers and voice, which isn't that different than learning coordination between limbs playing different rhythms or movements (eg. piano, drums). It takes practice, starting by being able to accurately and efficiently do those things separately, then going to gradually merge them, possibly by practising small sections repetitively and at different speeds.

Like bare chords, or singing over chords, the technique is not instant and you have to insist for a few days/weeks to know how to do it.
I find it closer to how bass players sing and play at the same time.

This is a classic example of “pat your head and rub your stomach in a circular motion at the same time”, or doing two independent things that are not necessarily that difficult on their own simultaneously. Many guitarists simplify their parts while singing and play complex lines in between their vocal phrases because doing what you want to do can be very challenging. It is certainly possible, it just takes coordination and practice. As a side note, pianists are often required to do this but with their left and right hands playing independently of each other.
There may be more but here are three basic approaches to being able to accomplish this:
The first way is to learn both parts individually but get to the point where one of the parts, say the syncopated guitar rhythm is so ingrained and automatic that you can play it without thinking, then start working the vocal part into the mix little by little.
The second way is to practice both parts together at an extremely slow tempo until you are comfortable gradually speeding it up.
The third way is to analyze the way the guitar and vocal parts interact, by writing them out in music notation on two staves. If you don’t read music then you can create a grid like I did below that vertically shows what happens both in the vocal and guitar. You can clearly see when they play together and when one plays alone. I used two bars of your example of “You Really Got Me” by The Kinks:

It is very easy to see how the two parts interact on this grid. Starting slowly and using something like this as a practice tool will eventually make it easy to play both parts simultaneously because you can clearly see the interaction and the independence in the same place.
Regarding your final three questions, any skill you learn, even if applied specifically to just one song will help improve your general progress over time because you will have already used similar problem solving techniques to accomplish new feats. This also works for bass since the two instruments are related. As a matter of fact, bassists are often better at this than guitarists because they almost exclusively play lines that are independent of the vocal parts.

There's no magic techniques needed here, except that obviously both your singing and playing should be fluent and efficient before trying to put them together - it's not going to work if your fingers are fumbling to find the next chord shape or you're struggling to remember the next word!
Just practice.   And the next song will be easier.
